# Using iPhone's microphone instead of headphone's for selected apps

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, headphones

I usually have Bluetooth headphones paired with an iPhone while I'm listening to music. However, now and then, I use the Voice Memos app or another app that requires a microphone. I only use those apps for a minute or so, then go back to listening to music through the headphones.

The headphones have a mic, but I prefer to use the iPhone's mic with those apps. However, while the headphones are paired with the iPhone, the apps default to the mic on the headphones. Therefore, whenever I use those apps I disconnect the headphones (by turning Bluetooth off), then I connect them again after I'm done using the microphone.

Is there a more practical way to do this?
Is it possible to automatically shift to the iPhone's mic instead of the headphones' mic for selected apps?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that there's any generic way to switch microphone inputs on iOS (except for the way you're doing it right now by disconnecting the Bluetooth device entirely).

The developers of an app can choose to provide the user with controls for choosing inputs. This is typically found in audio specific apps that do multi-routing - such as for example GarageBand or similar app. Developers can use the Apple provided AVAudioSession API to list available inputs, find the one with type `builtInMic` and then set it as the preferred input for that app. This is only possible to do for the app developer - it cannot be added on later by the user.